# Unable to save anything in the SAVED SEARCH in webtop. Documentum

Tags: documentum, webtop

When a user added to a group, they are able to see the documents and search the documents in webtop.

They can also see the SAVED SEARCH option there. It this the saved search which are created by other are visible(if they are shared with the user).

But the issue is when they try to save a new search results here, it doesn't work.
Though other users who have same access to the group are able to save.[image: Saved Search Issue]

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try check the permits on the saved search object.

Comment: Where can I find that?